# Redirect url to ip using router

Tags: redirect, proxy, router, iptables, beta

We have a server that is set up as a clone of production. Currently, we are able to hit this clone by changing our host file in windows. Some people are very confused by this. So, I am looking to set up a router to redirect all web traffic to the production URL namespace to the cloned server's ip address. Ex: www.foo.com/bar.html to 11:111:11:111/bar.html

I have seen some options with proxies, openDNS, etc. What I have available:

- Win 7 PC
- Win 10 PC
- macOS
- Linksys router (model WRT54GL)
- Airport extreme router (model A1408)
- Android phones + tablet
- ipods, ipads + iphones

We can order other devices or set up VMs as needed. I was also looking at setting up a raspberry pi with openWRT if that is easier than flashing the linksys. I am looking for advice on the best option to set up this network.

Comment: You need a dns server! Create the zone in your dns and redirect the domain you need to the ip you need and that's all. If you have control of the DHCP on the network you can put that dns for all machines. If is an "ilicit" attack, you can do a starvation attack and then set up your own DHCP with your DNS. Or you can do ARP poisonning to change the DNS cache of the machines forcing them to that ip instead of the real one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! We are going to order a Linksys LRT214 VPN Router to set up the local DNS database to connect the namespace directly to the ip address per their guide here: http://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=164492

Then we can set up one of the wifi routers to the dns of the vpn router. (hopefully it's that easy...)

Comment: Update: we are deciding to use one device using DD-WRT and DNSMasq. Buffalo makes routers with DD-WRT preinstalled.

Read more about setting up DNSMasq on DD-WRT here: http://cybernetnews.com/local-internal-dns-ddwrt/